# Cannot deploy local charm due to "Forbidden" error

Tags: juju

JUJU 1.25.5

When I add my local charm :

```
juju deploy --repository=/path to/charms/ local:trusty/charmname --to 0
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR cannot upload charm: Post  https://node-ip:17070/environment/31a84f6f-5b16-43c3-8f1f-e7b084301e1d/charms?series=trusty: Forbidden
```

When I am looking at juju debug-log:

```
machine-0: 2016-06-02 01:03:18 ERROR juju.apiserver debuglog.go:102 debug-log handler error: write tcp node-ip:17070->MAAS-ip:50036: write: broken pipe
machine-0: 2016-06-02 01:03:18 ERROR juju.apiserver debuglog.go:102 debug-log handler error: write tcp node-ip:17070->MAAS-ip:50036: write: broken pipe
```